# How to Update a Row Inside a While Loop In a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm new to SQL and I'm coding a stored procedure but can't get it to do what I want.

In the stored procedure, I have a while loop running and not throwing any exemptions except my row I want to update in each line of the table doesn't update even though it is executing the query's inside the if statements in the while loop.

I would be much obliged if someone could explain to me what is going wrong here.

The stored procedure returns the table but the `CommmissionRateID` column has been unchanged.

I have attached one of the IF..ELSE statements that are causing the problems

```
IF (@SalePrice * 100) / @ListPrice > 50
BEGIN
     SET @CommisionRateID = 3;

     SELECT * FROM CarDetails

     UPDATE CarDetails
     SET CommissionRateID = @CommisionRateID
     FROM CarDetails
     WHERE CarID = (@i + 1)
END
```

Thanks,

Comment: I don't think you need to loop for this--which isn't you question--but  you'll be happy figuring out to write this set based. And if you can provide some sample data in CarDetail and expect result you'll get better help quicker.

Comment: In the the final IF..ELSE block you are doing an UPDATE for the 1st and 3rd sections, and an INSERT for the middle one. Is what you want? I'm surprised it even compiles to be honest.

Comment: @KarlKieninger I wanted as sproc to automatically assign a commission rate to sales that have not been inputted previously in 3 different categories. I have tried 10 different ways of trying to update the column for each record but none works this program runs with this one but still no result??

Comment: @DeanOC Apologies for that I must of been trying different ways before I cut and paste it here the middle IF...ELSE block prob doesn't work as you have noted but any ideas on the UPDATE all I need is to update the record in the CommissionRateID column to the value that has been set above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you are not declaring variables, you're actually declaring parameters which you are using like variables.

Apart from `@CommisionRateID`, every one of the parameters will have any original value overwritten before the original value could be used.Unless you need to pass a value into the SP and use it, then you should remove it from the parameter list and declare it in the body of the proc.

Regarding `@CommisionRateID` you never change the original value and it is used to determine whether or not you do anything at all. So I'm guessing that you are trying to use it as a criteria so that you only update records where the current value is NULL. In which case you don't need this parameter either

On the assumption that you want to set the commission rate for the cars based on the SalePrice & ListPrice, where there isn't a commission rate currently, I think that all your code can be replaced with the following:

```
CREATE PROC spAssignCommissionRate
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE CarDetails
    SET CommissionRateID = CASE WHEN (SalePrice * 100) / ListPrice > 50 THEN 3
                                 WHEN (SalePrice * 100) / ListPrice > 30 THEN 2 
                                 ELSE 1
                            END
    WHERE CommissionRateID IS NULL
END
```

EDIT: IF anyone is wondering how the heck I inferred all this from the OPs code, I'm not actually psychic. Please take a look at the original version of the post.

Comment: Inferring it even from the original is quite a feat, even if not quite psychic. +1 for the set based conversion so quickly.